# why exe and pdb files are created on different folders?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, configuration

I'm building a C++ project in VS 2013, and after the build the exe and the pdb output files are not created at the same folder.

for example, the MyProject.exe is created on *\solution\target\MyProject.exe* and MyProject.pdb at \solution\target\**Debug**\MyProject.pdb

The default settings of the *Output Directory* was **$(SolutionDir)\target\$(Configuration)\** 
If I omit the **$(Configuration)**, the Debug folder is not created, and both of the files are created at the same folder (e.g \solution\target).

The problem is that currently I need to manually move the exe file to the Debug directory to be able to debug the program.

Is there a setting I can change for this? It's weird!

Thanks,
Ariel

Comment: well, I guess I don't really need to, and I'm missing some configuration. In the current state, if I leave it as it is after building - it just give me an error that it doesn't find the exe, cause he's searching it in the debug directory. Maybe you know what I'm missing here?

Comment: If you need to move the exe you're doing something wrong or doing something you're not telling us. The path to the PDB file is stored in the .exe file and when you launch the debugger through VS it knows the path to the executable. Review the project settings you've changed and provide _relevant_ information about your problem.

Comment: Ok, I found it. It was misconfigured at my workspace. Under Configuration Properties-> Linker-> General, the _Output File_ path wasn't the same as the one set to the pdb file path. That was the reason for my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the mistake was in misconfiguration of the project settings.

Both of those settings should point to the same location:

- Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> **Output Directory**
- Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> **Output File** (the .exe file).

In my case, the **Output File** wasn't pointing to the *$(Configuration)* (e.g *Debug/Release*) as the **Output Directory** was. It was pointing one level higher.